# Functional optimization with constraints that are not continuously differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let's say $x(\cdot)$ is a continuous function over $t$. The problem is to find a $x$ such that

$\int_{-1}^1 t^3 x(t) dt$ is maximized. The constraint is $\int_{-1}^1|x(t)|^3 dt \leq 2$. I was trying to use Euler-Lagrange equation to find an $x$. The problem is how to develop a Euler-Lagrange equation for this problem.  Would Holder's inequality be of any help?

Comment: Hint: If we restrict ourselves to $t > 0$, then it is obviously ideal to have $x(t)\geq 0$. Have you tried maximizing $\int_0^1 t^3x(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ subject to $\int_0^1 x(t)^3\,\mathrm{d}t\leq 1$?

Comment: Why do you write that the constraint non differentiable?

Comment: @copper.hat Because $|x(t)|^3$ is not differentiable which means I cannot obtain a Euler-Lagrange equation

Comment: The function $y \mapsto |y|^3$ **is** differentiable. I don't understand why you say it is not?

Comment: It **is** continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Hölder's inequality here rather than Euler Lagrange.

Take $L^3[-1,1]$ and define
$f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 t^3 x(t) dt $.

We see that $f$ is linear, and the constraint is $\|x\|_3 \le \sqrt[3]{2}$.

The problem becomes:
$\max \{ f(x) | \|x\|_3 \le \sqrt[3]{2} \}$.

Hölder's inequality gives $|f(x)| \le \|\phi\|_{3 \over 2} \| x\|_3$, where $\phi(t) = t^3$.

Note that $\|\phi\|_{3 \over 2} = \sqrt[3]{4^2 \over 11^2}$. We have
equality **iff** $ | {x(t) \over \|x\|_3 }|^3 = |{ \phi(t) \over \| \phi \|_{3 \over 2} } |^{3 \over 2}$ for ae. $t \in [-1,1]$.

Letting $x(t) = (\operatorname{sgn} t)\sqrt[3]{22 \over 4}\sqrt{|t^3|}$, we obtain
$\max \{ f(x) | \|x\|_3= \sqrt[3]{2} \}= \sqrt[3]{2^5 \over 11^2}$.

Since $x$ is continuous, it solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought it that way.